# How to insert posts using blogger api nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, blogger

According to Docs, I have authenticated my app on `request call` and try to insert a post:

```
var blogger = google.blogger('v3');
app.post('/creatGoogleBloggerPost', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('creatGoogleBloggerPost called');
    var oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2();
    var key = require('./public_html/SoulSeeker2-1bxxxaaa727d.json');
    var jwtClient;

    jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger'], null);
    jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
        console.log('retrieved tokens.access_token from google', tokens.access_token);
        google.options({
            auth: jwtClient
        });
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } else {
            blogger.posts.insert({
                auth: jwtClient,
                blogId: '4113791741191234135',
                resource: {
                  title: 'Sample rootscope',
                  content: 'Content rootscope'
                }
            }, function(){
                console.log('success');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I am getting the token back and also it prints the call back `success message` but however, no post is inserted when I check the blog. There is no error either. What could be wrong here?

**Update:**

Actually `google-blogger-api` doesn't accept service account token. So modify my code to use `oauth2.0` with `node-passport` but still getting `login error`:

```
blogger.posts.insert({
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' +USERS.accessToken,
    blogId: '4113796741591234135',
    resource: {
      title: 'Sample rootscope',
      content: 'Content rootscope'
    }
    }, function(err, reponse){
    if(err){
        console.log('error ', err);
    } else {
        console.log('blog post success in google blogger' , reponse);
    }
});
```

I have passed the auth `token` but I get error like this now:

```
error  { [Error: Login Required]
  code: 401,
  errors:
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'required',
       message: 'Login Required',
       locationType: 'header',
       location: 'Authorization' } ] }
```

I am using official google [blogger api](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples/blogger). I guess I am not passing the token in the header. How do I properly pass the token to fix this issue?

Comment: If the blogId mentioned in the above code ( 4113791741191234135 ) is the actual one and not a dummy, then that might be the cause of the problem as no blog exists with that Blog ID

Comment: @Verma it's an actual one but for security reasons I have alerted it while posting question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took so many days to properly figure this out using nodejs way (without using passportjs). Hope this helps.

One more way posting to blogger API is as follows:

Note: I am using nodejs with expressjs.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var rp = require('request-promise');

app.get('/creatGoogleBloggerPost', blogPost);
app.get("/auth/google/Bloggercallback", blogCallBack);
```

Get Auth Client:

```
function getOAuthClient() {
    return new OAuth2('client id', 'client secret', 'callback url');
}
```

Get Auth Url:

```
function getAuthUrl() {
    var oauth2Client = getOAuthClient();
    var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger'
    });
    return url;
}

function blogPost(req, res, next) {
    var params = {
        name: "sample",
        auth: getAuthUrl()
    };
    console.log('');
    console.log('=======================================================================');
    console.log('blogger api auth url: ', params);
    console.log('=======================================================================');
    console.log('');
    res.send(params.auth); //on the front-end view, I am doing window.location.replace to route `params.auth`
}
```

post to blogger inside callback:

```
function blogCallBack(req, res, next) {

    var oauth2Client = getOAuthClient();
    var code = req.query.code;
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function (err, tokens) {

        if (!err) {
            oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
            console.log('');
            console.log('===============================================================');
            console.log('BloggerAPI Callback....');
            console.log('Success Getting BloggerAPI Token', tokens);
            console.log('===============================================================');
            console.log('');

            var params = {
                title: 'Sample title',
                content: 'Sample Content'
            };

            var options = {
                uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/1939594269984333602/posts/',
                method: 'POST',
                body: params,
                headers: {
                    'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise',
                    "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + tokens.access_token
                },
                json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
            };

            rp(options)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('=================================');
                console.log('=================================');
                console.log("RESPONSE.STATUSCODE: ", res.statusCode);
                console.log('=================================');
                console.log('=================================');
                if (res.statusCode >= 100 && res.statusCode < 600)
                    return res.redirect('/');
                else
                    return res.status(500);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('=================================');
                console.log('=================================');
                console.log('POST error ', err.stack);
                console.log('=================================');
                console.log('=================================');
                return res.status(res.statusCode).send(err);
            });

        } else {
            console.log('Error Getting BloggerAPI Token', err);
        }
    });
}
```

The only problem is I am passing hard-coded values to post the blog in the callback. If anyone can help me out with that it would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The actual problem is I can't pass raw `access token`, I need to wrap it like this:

```
authObj = new  google.auth.OAuth2();
authObj.setCredentials({
    access_token: USERS.accessToken
});
```

The above "wrapping part" is not documented apparently for `blogger-api`

And then pass it in the below call as in `auth:authObj`:

```
blogger.posts.insert({
    auth: authObj,
    blogId: '4113796741591234135',
    resource: {
      title: 'Sample rootscope',
      content: 'Content rootscope'
    }
    }, function(err, reponse){
    if(err){
        console.log('error ', err);
    } else {
        console.log('blog post success in google blogger' , reponse);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is the token, like you need to encrypt it.

```
blogger.posts.insert({
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + btoa(USERS.accessToken),
    blogId: '4113796741591234135',
    resource: {
      title: 'Sample rootscope',
      content: 'Content rootscope'
    }
    }, function(err, reponse){
    if(err){
        console.log('error ', err);
    } else {
        console.log('blog post success in google blogger' , reponse);
    }
});
```